# Breaking loops with a conditional that looks at past results generated by loop? Setting conditional on an earlier value in a vector

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to break a loop by having a conditional that checks whether the last value of each of three vectors satisfies a particular condition that that may have taken place at that iteration OR past iterations of the loop.

Below is a very simple version of what I am trying to do.

Consider the following loop:

```
period = c(1:100)

x1 = 6
x2 = 8
x3 = 10
x = c()

for(t in 1:length(period)){x[t] = sample(c(x1,x2,x3), size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6,0.35,0.05))}
```

I am just wondering how I can make it such that this loop stops once each value has been sampled at least once. That is, the loop stops when each of `x1,x2,x3` have been sampled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `while` loop and continue it until `all` the 3 values are not present in `x`.

```
x1 <- 6
x2 <- 8
x3 <- 10
i <- 1
x = c()
flag <- TRUE

while(flag){
  x[i] <- sample(c(x1,x2,x3), size = 1, prob = c(0.6,0.35,0.05))
  i <- i + 1
  if (all(c(x1, x2, x3) %in% x)) flag <- FALSE
}

x
#[1]  6  6  6  6  6  8  6  6  8  8  8  6  6  8  8  8  6  6  6  8 10
```

A variation without using `flag` :

```
while(TRUE){
  x[i] <- sample(c(x1,x2,x3), size = 1, prob = c(0.6,0.35,0.05))
  i <- i + 1
  if (all(c(x1, x2, x3) %in% x)) break
}
```

Comment: This looks promising! May I ask what the ```TRUE``` is doing in the while loop?

Comment: @NateRiver `while` accepts a boolean condition to test meaning the loop would run until that condition is satisfied. By using `TRUE` here we say that `while` loop would run forever but we use `break` inside it to stop the `while` loop from running after the condition in `if` is satisfied.